# Need help debugging slow NFS with high avg RTT on Ubuntu

Tags: network-interface, nfs, io, libvirt

I'm managing a number of libvirt hypervisors, where the VMs data is stored on a NFS server.

I've been experiencing high I/O wait on the hypervisors' CPUs, and as such decided to dig a little deeper. Output of `iotop` showed quite slow io speeds for the processes: [image: iotop Output DISK WRITE between 20 and 600 K/s]

I decided to take a look at the `nfsiostat`:

```bash
192.168.20.6:/vms/vmsfs mounted on /mnt/vms:

           ops/s       rpc bklog
         185.786           0.000

read:              ops/s            kB/s           kB/op         retrans    avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
                  13.158        2806.170         213.268        0 (0.0%)           7.583          23.431
write:             ops/s            kB/s           kB/op         retrans    avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
                 150.745        2750.688          18.247       31 (0.0%)          35.196         828.924
```

As you can see, the system reports a very high `avg RTT` and `avg exe`.

`nfsiostat -a` reported the following:

```bash
192.168.20.6:/vms/vmsfs mounted on /mnt/vms:

           ops/s       rpc bklog
         185.786           0.000

getattr:           ops/s            kB/s           kB/op         retrans    avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
                   5.631           2.326           0.413        0 (0.0%)           4.644          10.792
access:            ops/s            kB/s           kB/op         retrans    avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
                   0.001           0.000           0.344        0 (0.0%)           7.873           9.911

186771 VFS opens
15897283 inoderevalidates (forced GETATTRs)
9734677 page cache invalidations
159935979 attribute cache invalidations
```

Mount options are as follows:

```
192.168.20.6:/vms/vmsfs on /mnt/vms type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.20.4,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.20.6)
```

The hypervisors and NFS server are all directly attached to a single switch via SFP+ in a separate VLAN.
None of the connected systems shows overly high CPU or RAM usage.

I currently don't know where to go from here, and need help taking the right next steps in debugging this problem. I'd be very happy to receive your input.